# Reverse order blogger comments

Tags: javascript, blogger

Good morning. How can I show blog comments, created with bloggers, in reverse order: from the latest to the oldest. Only for some posts. thank you

Comment: Order them by date descending

Comment: how? this is the blog: http://divertimento-risate-scherzi.blogspot.it/

Answer (score 2):

You can count the length of comment and loop it to 0 and use the result for index example

```
<!-- Get the Post -->
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>

    <!-- It will loop from the length of comments to 0 to be used for index -->
    <!-- comment.length to 0 -->
    <b:loop values='data:post.comments.length &quot; to 0&quot;' var='i'>
        <data:comments[i].author/>
        <hr/>
    </b:loop>

</b:loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented only when using non-threaded comments. To configure your theme to use non-threaded comments rather than threaded comments, you will have to make changes in the `<b:includable id='comment_picker' var='post'>` block present inside the Blog widget. This block's code will be changed to -

```
<b:includable id='comment_picker' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.commentSource == 1'>
        <b:include data='post' name='comments'/>
    </b:if>
</b:includable>
```

After that, to reverse the order of comments find the following `b:loop` statement -

```
<!-- In v2 themes, present inside <b:includable id='comments' var='post'> -->
<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' >
```

```
<!-- In v3 themes, present inside <b:includable id='commentList' var='comments'> -->
<b:loop values='data:post.comments' var='comment'>
```

Add the `reverse` attribute to the `b:loop` statement, so that code looks like -

```
<!-- In v2 themes-->
<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' reverse='1'>
```

```
<!-- In v3 themes-->
<b:loop values='data:post.comments' var='comment' reverse='1'>
```

To make this applicable on some of the posts, you will have to wrap the `b:loop` statement with a `b:if` statement (which uses the condition of either Post URL or PostID)

Comment: The line does not exist:
<b:includable id='commentList' var='comments'> 

There is not even the word: "commentList"

Comment: @VincenzoIavazzo `commentList` is only present in v3 themes that were released on March 20, 2017 (Refer to https://blogger.googleblog.com/2017/03/share-your-unique-style-with-new.html) If you use any one of those new themes, then only will you likely come across `commentList` in the code

Comment: If I replace:
`<b:includable id='comments' var='post'>`

with:
`<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' reverse='1'`

The error appears:
The element type "b:loop" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</b:loop>"


So I replaced:
`</b:includable>`

with:
`</b:loop>`

And this time the error appears:
The widget with id "Blog1" cannot contain element: "b:loop". A widget can only contain b:includable elements.

did I do something wrong?
thank you

Comment: @VincenzoIavazzo You do not need to replace `<b:includable id='comments' var='post'>` with `<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' reverse='1' >`  . Instead you need to replace `<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' >` with  `<b:loop values='data:comments' var='comment' reverse='1' >` (or as you will notice, simply add the `reverse='1'` attribute to that `b:loop` statement) as well as change the `comment_picker`'s `b:includable` tag to use non-threaded comments

Comment: Works with a blog created in 2017.
It does not work with a blog created in 2008.
Do you know why?
Anyway, that's fine.
thank you so much. You are a true expert.

Comment: If I make these changes, no comments are posted on the blog created in 2008